# delete selected rowdata in datatable vb

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Hey guys how to delete data on datatable

my code where i delete data and the result just remove data from grid not datatable

my current code

```
selectStr = "AccrualNo = '" & bauAccrual  & "' AND GLAccountID = '" & bauGL &"' AND PCCodeID = '" & bauPC  & "'"
    rowToDelete = TempTable.Select(selectStr)(0)
    rowToDelete.Delete
    TempTable.AcceptChanges
    BAU_grdTransactions.DataSource = TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string selectStr = "primary_key =" + pk
DataRow rowToDelete = dataTable.Select(selectStr)(0)
dataTable.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete)
```

`primary_key` is the Primary Key of your data table. `pk` value you can extract from the GridView. if `pk` is string, use in single quotes.

Comment: Hi Sunil , 
after i try your code its same like my current , when i delete data , the data just removed not deleted.

this my current code now i will edit my code

Comment: Do you mean to delete from database? then you need to call update on your adapter `myDataAdapter.Update(dataTable)`